# What's a unique identifier in listsinceblock output?

Tags: listtransactions

I am trying to understand if there a unique identifier for transactions. I didn't find anything about that mentioned in [listsinceblock](http://chainquery.com/bitcoin-api/help/listsinceblock)'s help.

```
{
  "involvesWatchonly": true,
  "account": "",
  "address": "mvd6qFeVkqH6MNAS2Y2cLifbdaX5XUkbZJ",
  "category": "receive",
  "amount": 10,
  "label": "",
  "confirmations": 69,
  "blockhash": "62967ce950fc03b14179e58f42e426b63cbfbf63c2b9e59acb6a719a09c23b94",
  "blockindex": 58,
  "blocktime": 1524872287278,
  "txid": "aac9b2d7bb7b3476a83a5ac0c2fe21625bcd961ed43a5c5fd3eacf6536dc81d5",
  "vout": 7,
  "walletconflicts": [],
  "time": 1524872276635,
  "timereceived": 1524872276635,
  "bip125-replaceable": "no"
},
```

Comment: What do you mean by "unique key of transactions over time"? `listsinceblock` does not tell you how many transactions occurred over a given amount of time, it only tells you what transactions and you can then calculate it yourself.

Comment: @AndrewChow if I do 2 calls or listsinceblock I want not to count the same transaction twice.

Comment: RPC calls are stateless, they do not remember the last time you made that call and do not do anything related to "time since last RPC call". The only way to avoid counting the same transaction twice is to just use the hash of the block that was found after your last call to `listsinceblock`

Comment: @AndrewChow that's why I need to take care of it. Then I want a unique identifier

Answer (score 0):

Each transaction has a unique identifier which is the `txid`. It is the hash of the transaction and each transaction's hash is unique.

Comment: No, one txid can cause multiple entries in the `list*` RPCs. You need to also include "vout" to have a unique key.

Comment: @PieterWuille what is considered a valid "receive" transaction from listsinceblock that I would about to credit? If say same txid occurs in 2 transactions but with different vout, should both transactions be credited? What if 2 transactions have same txid and vout? Thank you

Comment: Yes you should credit both. The same txid/vout combination can't appear multiple times.